# Verifying private and public RSA keys match

Tags: java, openssl, rsa

I've loaded two keys and I want to verify them after I've signed something with one of them, but I a having difficulties. I am getting "verified: false" at the end without any error. Can someone please point out the flaw?

```
package fliesigning;

import static fliesigning.FlieSigning.verifySig;
import java.io.*;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.security.*;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.Provider;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPrivateKey;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.RSAPrivateKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;

public class Signing {
  private static final String BEGIN_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY = "<PRIVATE KEY>";
  private static final String BEGIN_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY = "<PUBLIC KEY>";

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // Remove the first and last lines
    String privKeyPEM = BEGIN_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY.replace("-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n", "");
    privKeyPEM = privKeyPEM.replace("-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----", "");
    System.out.println(privKeyPEM);

    String publicKeyPEM = BEGIN_RSA_PUBLIC_KEY.replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n", "");
    publicKeyPEM = publicKeyPEM.replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");
    System.out.println(publicKeyPEM);

    // Base64 decode the data
    Base64 b64 = new Base64();
    byte [] encoded = b64.decode(privKeyPEM);
    byte [] encoded_pub = b64.decode(publicKeyPEM);

    // PKCS8 decode the encoded RSA private key
    PKCS8EncodedKeySpec privateKeySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
    KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(privateKeySpec);

    X509EncodedKeySpec publicKeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(encoded_pub);
    KeyFactory pk = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
    PublicKey publicKey = pk.generatePublic(publicKeySpec);

    // Display the results
    System.out.println(privKey);
    String file = "qwerty";
    byte[] fileBytes = file.getBytes();
    byte[] digitalSignature = signData(fileBytes, privKey);
    System.out.println("SIGNATURE MADE");
    boolean verified;
    verified = verifySig(fileBytes, publicKey, digitalSignature);
    System.out.println("verified: " + verified) ;
  }

  public static byte[] signData(byte[] data, PrivateKey key) throws Exception {
    Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    signer.initSign(key);
    signer.update(data);
    return (signer.sign());
  }

  public static boolean verifySig(byte[] data, PublicKey key, byte[] sig) throws Exception {
    Signature signer = Signature.getInstance("SHA256withRSA");
    signer.initVerify(key);
    signer.update(data);
    return (signer.verify(sig));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code appears to work fine, it must be that your keys actually don't match. I created some test keys using:

- `openssl genrsa -out priv.pem`
  *(create basic RSA private key)*
- `openssl rsa -in priv.pem -pubout -out pub.pem`
  *(extract public key)*
- `openssl pkcs8 -in priv.pem -out pk8.pem -topk8 -nocrypt`
  *(convert private key to unencrypted PKCS#8 format)*

This gave me two files to test with: `pk8.pem` and `pub.pem`. I changed your code slightly so that the begin and end markers were `-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----` and `-----END PRIVATE KEY-----`.

The verification passed successfully.

Comment: Ah, it works, thank you! Just want to ask if I can optimize the code somehow, make it better?

Comment: And another question, how can I read the key from a file instead of a string?

Comment: @davidguetta Your first question might be suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com. Check the help pages before you post there. For the second question, I think Google will help you there.